# Display a key in a multi-level Json

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

- I have an auto-generated multi-level Json from a Servlet. then i display this Json in e it's (key, value) in a modal dialog inside an HTML using a script in AngularJS. The modal dialog have many tabs,  each tab is named with the key of the Json and inside in theory the values.
- What I want is to display the correspondents values correctly and not all the object, inside tabs.
- That's my Json

  ```
      {
        "mission": {
          "codice": "4",
          "descrizione": "Missione aerea",
          "nome": "New Mombasa",
          "location": "Bari"
        },
        "equipments": {
          "radio": "no radio",
          "drone": "UAV",
          "minerobot": "no robot",
          "binoculars": "binoculars"
        },
        "weapons": {
          "gun": "Beretta",
          "machinegun": "Heavy Machine Gun",
          "rocketlauncher": "",
          "bombs": "granades",
          "shotgun": ""
        },
        "crew": {
          "team": "Team Bravo",
          "agent": ""
        },
        "veicles": {
          "car": "4x4",
          "submarine": "",
          "jet": "f-16",
          "ship": ""
        }
      }
  ```
- and this is the part who generate the modal dialog

  ```
      <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html" >
          <div class="modal-content">
              <div class ="modal-header">
                  <h3 class ="modal-title">Dettaglio Missione {{Items.nome}}{{Items.mission.nome}} Codice:{{Items.codice}}{{Items.mission.codice}}</h3>
              </div>

              <br>

              <div class="bs-example bs-example-tabs">
                  <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
                      <li class="" ng-repeat="(key, value) in Items"><a href="#{{key}}" data-toggle="tab">{{key}}</a></li>
                  </ul>
              </div>

              <div class="modal-body">
                  <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
                      <div class="tab-pane fade in" ng-repeat="(key, value) in Items" id="{{key}}">

                              {{value}}

                      </div>
                  </div>

              <div class="modal-footer">
              <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
              <button class="btn btn-warning" type="submit" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
              </div>
          </div>
      </script>
  ```
- in the photo there is the result, as you can see the tabs are correctly displayed but the {{value}} shows all the json and not only the values.

[image: Modal Dialog Photo]

Comment: `value` is the whole weapons object so you could use another loop to loop through the `weapons` object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `{{value}}`
with

```
{{value.gun}}
{{value.machinegun}}
{{value.rocketlauncher}}
{{value.bombs}}
{{value.shotgun}}
```

or replace with loop:

```
<div class="type" ng-repeat="(k, v) in value">
    {{k}}:{{v}} 
</div>
```

Comment: This is right. Because your value is JavaScript object and because you pass it in the template, angular doesn't know what to do with it and dump the entire object.

Comment: thousand of thanks! i solve my problem. i was in mistake cause i was trying to resolve in this wrong way. {{item.gun}} for example...You know where i can learn something right about Json?

Comment: from stackoverflow